# Python regex greek characters

Tags: python, regex, string, extract, placeholder

I have some strings which have this structure: `<name> (<unit>)`. I would like to extract `name` and `unit`; to perform this task I use `regex` and in most cases it is all fine.
However, in some cases the `<unit>` is formed by greek characters, like `Ω`. In these cases, my code fails to extract the two desired parts.
Here is my code:

```
import re

def name_unit_split(text):
    name = re.split(' \([A-Za-z]*\)', text)[0]
    unit = re.findall('\([A-Za-z]*\)', text)

    if unit != []:
        unit = unit[0][1:-1]
    else:
        unit = ''

    return name, unit

print(name_unit_split('distance (mm)'))
```

and I get:

```
('distance', 'mm')
```

But when I try with:

```
print(name_unit_split('resistance (Ω)'))
```

I get:

```
('resistance (Ω)', '')
```

I searched for other regex placeholders and try to use these, without success:

```
name = re.split(' \([\p{Greek}]*\)', text)[0]
unit = re.findall('\([\p{Greek}]*\)', text)
```

How can I find greek characters (one or more, grouped) in a string using `regex`?
Furthermore, is there a better way to perform the above described task using `regex`? I mean: there is a way to extract both `<name>` and `<unit>` and save them in `name` and `unit` with `regex`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just like Latin alphabets, Greek alphabets occupy a continuous space in the utf-8 encoding, so you can use `\([α-ωΑ-Ω]*\)` instead of `\([A-Za-z]*\` to construct your regex.

I would personally prefer to use a regex like `"[A-Za-z]* \([α-ωΑ-Ω]*\)"` to check if the pattern holds and use string functions to do split jobs. But I believe it depends on your personal preference.

Answer (score 2):

A no-regex solution for the structure `<name> (<unit>)` is [`str.partition`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition):

```
>>> name, _, unit = "resistance (Ω)"[:-1].partition(" (")
>>> name
'resistance'
>>> unit
'Ω'
```